# Почему не получается? Фон-картинка в блоке div

Tags: css, html

Есть такая проблема: уже неделю пытаюсь поставить на `div` картинку-фон. Но в браузере ничего не отображается. Из-за этого не могу проект выложить. Почему не работает?

```css
.game1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  background-image: url("screenshot.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="game1">
  <p class="name"> Бла </p>
  <p class="description"> Бла <br> бла <br> бла бла бла! </p> <br> <br> <br>
  <a href="games/radiation.php"> <button id="b1"> Перейти </button> </a>
</div> <br> <br> <br> <br>
```

Картинку засовывал и в корень сайта, и в папку с `CSS`, и на сервер заливал, прописывал `URL` через `http`, не работает.

Comment: Научитесь пользоваться отладчиком Google Chrome (F12). Раздел Networks вам поможет понять, почему не загружается картинка

Comment: Сделайте код [запускаемым](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4619/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B) и воспроизведите там вашу проблему.

Answer (score 3):

И что тут может не работать?

```css
.game1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  background-image: url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--zTY0m0ci--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1359563471926476945.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.game1 p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="game1">
  <p class="name"> Бла </p>
  <p class="description"> Бла <br> бла <br> бла бла бла! </p> <br> <br> <br>
  <a href="games/radiation.php"> <button id="b1"> Перейти </button> </a>
</div> <br> <br> <br> <br>
```

Comment: Я это и хочу узнать

Comment: Сделайте нерабочий сниппет, вам уже написали. Другими словами, Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Сделай папку img, туда засунь эту картинку и сделай такой путь, если файл со стилями у тебя в папке css.

```
background-image: url("../img/screenshot.jpg");
```

Comment: у меня есть папка images, путь я прописывал. Нужно попробовать опять.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавит !important перед ; в css background-image